# Change day start and end time

Tags: r, datetime

How can I force R to change the parameters of a day. So I mean that for example yrDay like here provided doesn't go from 0am til 0am but from 6pm til 6pm.

```
df <- data.frame(Date=seq(
        from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 13:00:00", tz="UTC"),
        to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 13:00:00", tz="UTC"),
        by="hour")
)
df$yrDay <- as.numeric(strftime(df$Date,format="%j"))
```

Comment: Is this for quick-and-dirty purposes, or do you want something robust against all the trick date/time stuff that comes up (daylight savings, leap seconds/days, local law changes, and on and on it goes.) Dates and times are *hard* if you want to be really accurate. But if perfection is the enemy of the good, just add the relevant constant when you do the calculation and go with that.

Comment: I  need it for daily cycle analysis of body temperatures. I see it is not that robust but hopefully enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 5 hours (5 * 60 min * 60 sec) using your code:

```
df$yrDay <- as.numeric(strftime(df$Date + 5*60*60,format="%j"))

                  Date yrDay
1  2012-01-01 13:00:00     1
2  2012-01-01 14:00:00     1
3  2012-01-01 15:00:00     1
4  2012-01-01 16:00:00     1
5  2012-01-01 17:00:00     1
6  2012-01-01 18:00:00     2
7  2012-01-01 19:00:00     2
8  2012-01-01 20:00:00     2
9  2012-01-01 21:00:00     2
10 2012-01-01 22:00:00     2
...
```

Or 6 hours using `lubridate` (better approach IMHO):

```
df$yrDay <- lubridate::day(df$Date + 6*60*60)
```

But as mentioned by @ngm in the comments, it is a quick and dirty solution that might not be robust for all cases.

Comment: Similar question was posted by another user 15mins before. Here's my alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518384/sort-datetime-data-by-day-but-from-4pm-to-4pm

Comment: I see he was a little bit faster. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A robust solution in python code for the Q above.

This algorithm uses a NumPy and pandas to set a conditions for each time in with your datetime data. It simply ask if the day before is less then the time specified and the is date == to the current date.

Then it ask and if the day after is greater then shift hour and is it  This condition been generate for each day in your data then is check for date same as the before day.

Hope this help or encourage other to try think for better solution.

Sorry about my English it is not my first and I am very busy so this is my best for the time i allocate to make an answer. Hope to improve please give helpful comments and try not to harsh :)

```py
def count_custome_day_start_and_end(pd_index_datetime, shift_time='8:30am'):
    dates = sorted(set(pd_index_datetime.date))
    times = np.array([time.time() for time in pd_index_datetime
                      ])
    shift_time = pd.to_datetime(shift_time).time()
    conditiones = [
        cond for date in dates for cond in [
            ((times < shift_time)
             & (pd_index_datetime.date == date)),  # day before
            ((times >= shift_time)
             & (pd_index_datetime.date == date))   # day after
        ]
    ]
    langth = (len(conditiones) // 2) + 1
    choices = [0, *np.repeat(range(1, langth), 2)]
    choices.pop()
    return np.select(conditiones, choices, pd_index_datetime.factorize()[0])
```